# Comparator interface not compiling and having trouble sorting array twice

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compareto, alphabetical

The assigment asks for the user to sort path names by number of slashes and in lexicographic order. The specific instructions are "Your task is to sort an array list of path names such as

```
\home\me\cs1
\usr\share
\var\log
\usr\local\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib
```

FileName is to read in the path names and then sort the path length, i.e. the number of slashes in the path name. Path names of the same length should be arranged in lexicographic order (i.e. by calling String.compareTo.) For example, the path names given above will be sorted as "

```
\usr\share
\var\log
\home\me\cs1
\usr\local\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib
```

Heres the code I have so far. I'm having trouble in that I keep getting an error that says it cannot find the cymbol "Collections at line 38" and "interface expected at line 13". I'm also not sure how to sort the arraylist lexicographic without messing up the order after I have sorted by slashes.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FileName implements Comparator<String>
{

    public FileName()
    {

    }


    private static int countSlashes(String p)
    {
        return p.length() - p.replace("/", "").length();
    }

    public int compareTo(String p1, String p2)
    {
        if (countSlashes(p1) < countSlashes(p2))
            return -1;
        if (countSlashes(p1) == countSlashes(p2))
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }

    public ArrayList sortArrays(ArrayList input)
    {
        return Collections.sort(input);
    }


    public interface Comparator<String>
    {
        int compare(String a, String b);
    }


}
```

.....

```
Tester Class
/**
 * @(#)FileNamePrgm.java
 *
 *
 * @author
 * @version 1.00 2015/4/2
 */
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FileNamePrgm
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many file names will you be entering?");
        int x=in.nextInt();
        ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Input file names");
        String file;
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            String fileN=in.nextLine();
            arr.add(fileN);
        }

        ArrayList sorted=FileName.sortArrays(arr);
        System.out.println("Sorted file names:");
        System.out.println(sorted);





    }


}
```

Comment: what is this `public interface Comparator<String>
    {
        int compare(String a, String b);
    }`

Comment: There are quite a few errors here. You should go back and review your course materials (esp. generics and `Comparable`/`Comparator`) because it's clear you don't have a full grasp on these concepts.

Comment: @javaProgrammer, did the discussion and answer provided helped you to solve your problem?

Comment: @javaProgrammer, could you kindly accept/vote the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `Collections` like this:

```
import java.util.Collections;
```

As for sorting, you can do it all in the same comparator. Where you now have:

```
if (countSlashes(p1) == countSlashes(p2))
    return 0;
```

Instead of returning `0` you compare both strings lexicographically and return that.

```
if (countSlashes(p1) == countSlashes(p2))
    return p1.compareTo(p2);
```

@Edit:

Also I think you want to use [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) instead of your own `Comparator`.

@Edit2:

Also this `p.replace("/", "")` creates a new `String` every time you call it which isn't the most efficient way. You could just loop over the string and count the number of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

1) When I tried your code, it was not taking input correctly, so I modified it to make sure all inputs are received.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // System.out.println("How many file names will you be entering?");
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out
            .println("Input file names and press (## to finish entering)");
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String fileName = in.nextLine();
        if (fileName.equals("##")) {
            break;
        }
        arr.add(fileName);
    }
    in.close();
```

I am using ## as escape sequence to finish read operation.

2) The next step is to have chain of Comparator. Please refer to example [Sorting by multiple attributes](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/sorting-a-list-by-multiple-attributes-example)

The problem you are trying to solve is similar. The first comparator will compare on number of slash characters and the second one will compare on alphabetic order.

For the second comparator, you can ignore slashes and compare. this will greatly simplify the code.

If you want to do it only with one comparator, here is comparator code

```
class FileNameComparator implements Comparator<String> {

@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

    // Compare slashes first
    int o1count = o1.length() - o1.replace("\\", "").length();
    int o2count = o2.length() - o2.replace("\\", "").length();

    if (o1count == o2count) {

        return o1.replace("\\", "").compareTo(o2.replace("\\", ""));

    } else {

        return o1count - o2count;
    }

}
}
```

Which can be simply called like

```
    Collections.sort(arr, new FileNameComparator());
    System.out.println("Sorted file names:" + arr);
    System.out.println(arr);
```